# How make type narrowing between event types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events

I have a function to which I pass an event. Event can be of two different types. The question is, how do I narrow down the types?

```
function test(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

I tried to do it in different ways, including through typeof but this obviously doesn't work.

It should turn out something like this:

```
 function test(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    if (typeof e === 'React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>') {
        const files = e.target.files;
    } else {
        const files = e.dataTransfer;
    }
}
```

Ok, I found the solution lol:

```
function test(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    if ('files' in e.target) {
        console.log(e.target.files);
    } else if ('dataTransfer' in e) {
        console.log(e.dataTransfer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you mean by narrowing down the type? Do you want to shorten the whole `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>` into a shorter type form?